# SwiftUI using Charts to create a RadarChart and wanting to update RadarChartDataEntry in realtime

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is it possible to edit the data entry for the Radar Charts realtime using iOS Charts https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts?

I am starting with a new chart with all zeros as such:

```
var newRadarDataSet = RadarChartDataSet (
    entries: [
        RadarChartDataEntry(value: 0),
        RadarChartDataEntry(value: 0),
        RadarChartDataEntry(value: 0),
        RadarChartDataEntry(value: 0),
        RadarChartDataEntry(value: 0)
   ]
)
```

And while the app is running I would like to update the chart based on input.

Can this be done?!

When I try to change the entries as such:

```
self.newRadarDataSet.entries[0] = RadarChartDataEntry(value: 10)
```

I get the following error:

`Cannot assign through subscript: 'entries' setter is inaccessible`

Does anyone know how to get around this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is possible approach. Tested with Xcode 11.4

*Note: `replaceEntries` notifies about changes automatically so chart will be updated as expected.*

[image: demo]

```
newRadarDataSet.replaceEntries(newRadarDataSet.entries.indices.map {
    $0 == 0 ? RadarChartDataEntry(value: 10) : newRadarDataSet.entries[$0]
})
```